# How to convert c datatype to neon datatype

Tags: c++, arm, vectorization, simd, neon

I am learning to optimise code using [ARM neon instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CIHJBEFE.html).I have a c++ function which performs a particular operation. Say for example,

```
int* multiplyCorrespondingElements(int* arr1, int* arr2)
```

arr1 and arr2 are two integer arrays of the same size n (n>50). This function should multiply the corresponding elements of the given arrays.

I want to implement the function using arm neon.  For using the neon functions, the data type should be something like

```
int8x8_t or int16x4_t or int32x2_t or int64x1_t.
```

and the function I need to use for multiplication is one of the functions given at

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CIHJBEFE.html

How can I convert the int [] which is available as the function parameter to the vector data types of arm neon? What is the criterions for deciding which vector I should use and which multiplication function I should use?

I searched a lot but could not find any similar example. All examples available on the net take a vector data type itself as the parameter. I cannot do that as the function need to be part of a larger c++ library and I can only change this function to optimise the performance.

Is there any tutorial for beginners using arm neon? Can anyone provide a simple example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would use vld intrinsics to load a vector of elements from each input array, e.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 4)               // iterate through arrays, 4 elements at a time
{
    int4x32_t v1 = vld1q_s32(&arr1[i]);  // load vector of 4 x 32 bit ints from arr1
    int4x32_t v2 = vld1q_s32(&arr2[i]);  // load vector of 4 x 32 bit ints from arr2
    int4x32_t vp = vmulq_s32(v1, v2);    // multiply vectors
    // ... do other stuff ...
    // ... store results  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. this was exactly what i needed. Can you suggest any tutorials for using neon intrinsics for beginners?

Comment: I don't know of any tutorials but I think there is an [SO user who might have been working on a book on NEON](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1021504/jake-alquimista-lee) - I believe he is an assembler purist though, and doesn't use intrinsics, so you would have to deal with that. I recommend going through all his answers on SO and also search for other answers with the `[neon]` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the link. May I ask one more related doubt? what are the functions usually used to convert neon datatype back to c datatype for example to a int array after the computations? is it vst1q_s32 in the current case?

Comment: Yes, `vst1q_s32` is probably what you want in this case - don't think of it as "conversion" though - you're just loading/storing scalar data to/from NEON vector registers.